# Extract values of dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
struct Country {
  var translations : [String:String?]? // must be defined as optionals!
}

// example entry
translationsDict = [
   "translations": [
      "de":"Deutschland", 
      "en": "germany",
      "it": nil
   ]
]
```

How can I extract the values "Deutschland" and "germany" into a new array?
result should be:

```
 ["germany", "Deutschland"]
```

Comment: translations is array??

Comment: translations is a dict made of key String and Value String? as you can see in the struct.

Comment: Why are the dictionary values optional? That's nonsensical. By definition a `nil` value indicates *key is missing*

Comment: Your `translations` dictionary is define to have string for key and string for value. However, why your `translationsDict` variable is defined with array as value? Are they not in the same type?

Comment: Because the response from the API could have empty values. I've updated my question and added a nil example, hope that makes it clearer

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, get a collection of all values of *translations*, then convert it to an array.

```
if let collection = translationsDict["translations"]?.values {
    let array = Array(collection)
    print(array)
}
```

or

```
if let array = translationsDict["translations"]?.map({ $0.1 }) {
    print(array)
}
```

Comment: Be careful "collection" in your example is ALSO A DICT with optional values